# Joining a Json attribute with Oracle Database column to get matching rows using JSON_TABLE - Oracle 19C

Tags: sql, json, oracle, json-table

This is on Oracle 19c Database.

I have a need to develop a DB view containing a traditional relational table and a json_table and only get filtered row based on a column from this relational table matching with one key from json table. How do I achieve this?

**Below is an example of the code.  Here only those rows from j_purchaseorder should return which have matching PONumber In Json table.**

```
CREATE VIEW j_purchaseorder_detail_view
  AS SELECT jt.*
       FROM j_purchaseorder po,
            json_table(po.po_document, '$'
              COLUMNS (
                po_number        NUMBER(10)         PATH '$.PONumber',
                reference        VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)  PATH '$.Reference',
                requestor        VARCHAR2(128 CHAR) PATH '$.Requestor',
                userid           VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)  PATH '$.User',
                costcenter       VARCHAR2(16)       PATH '$.CostCenter',
                ship_to_name     VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
                                 PATH '$.ShippingInstructions.name',
                ship_to_street   VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
                                 PATH '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.street',
                ship_to_city     VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
                                 PATH '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.city',
                ship_to_county   VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
                                 PATH '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.county',
                ship_to_postcode VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
                                 PATH '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.postcode',
                ship_to_state    VARCHAR2(2 CHAR)
                                 PATH '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.state',
                ship_to_zip      VARCHAR2(8 CHAR)
                                 PATH '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.zipCode',
                ship_to_country  VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
                                 PATH '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.country',
                ship_to_phone    VARCHAR2(24 CHAR)
                                 PATH '$.ShippingInstructions.Phone[0].number',
                NESTED PATH '$.LineItems[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                    itemno      NUMBER(38)         PATH '$.ItemNumber', 
                    description VARCHAR2(256 CHAR) PATH '$.Part.Description', 
                    upc_code    NUMBER             PATH '$.Part.UPCCode', 
                    quantity    NUMBER(12,4)       PATH '$.Quantity', 
                    unitprice   NUMBER(14,2)       PATH '$.Part.UnitPrice'))) jt;
```

Please advise.
Thank you
Darsh

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for a **minimal** example of the problem (i.e. you can include only 2-3 columns in the table and 2-5 nested JSON properties then only include the minimum and not 20); an English (not code) explanation of how the input data should be transformed to the output data; the issues/errors with your existing code; and the expected output for that sample data. At the moment the question is difficult to answer because you don't say what you are starting from nor what you expect as the output.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the premise of

*Here only those rows from j_purchaseorder should return which have matching PONumber In Json table*

I am assuming you have a column in J_PURCHASEORDER that you want to match to jt.po_number ? Let's call that column PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER.

In that case, is not this just a standard join ? eg

```
CREATE VIEW j_purchaseorder_detail_view
  AS SELECT jt.*
       FROM j_purchaseorder po,
       ...
       ...
  WHERE jt.PO_NUMBER = po.PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER
```